# Meteor HTTP.call and jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, http, meteor

I would like to use Meteor.call('GET') instead of $.ajax(). I have an ajax call as the following:

```
$.ajax({                                                                                         
    url: url,                                                                                           
    crossDomain:true,                                                                                   
    type: method,                                                                                       
    data: query,                                                                                        
    dataType: 'json'                                                                                    
}).done(function(data) {                                                                               
    _tokens.request = {                                                                                
    token: data.oauth_token,                                                                       
    secret: data.oauth_token_secret.split('')                                                      
};                                                                                                 
});
```

Have some options but I don't know how to pass to Meteor.call(). Please help!
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean `HTTP.call` or `HTTP.get`. `Meteor.call` is related to another concept.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_get

Comment: Yes. I tried to do this.

Meteor.http.call('POST', url, {data: query }, function(err, data) { });    
But how to enable crossDomain with meteor.http.call?    
Thank you!